# How can I target a child element within a parent element using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So here is the following HTML code

```html
<div>
    <div id='parent-1'>
        <div classname="fiasd">
          <div classname="ehuh">
             <div classname ="target-me-1">
             </dv>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='parent-1'>
        <div classname="fiasd">
          <div classname="ehuh">
             <div classname ="target-me-1">
             </dv>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='parent-1'>
        <div classname="fiasd">
          <div classname="ehuh">
             <div classname ="target-me-1">
             </dv>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**MY APPROACH**

I am using selenium to find all the elements with classname="parent-1" which gives me a list of 3 elements. Now what I want to do is target the element 'target-me-1' using the reference from the parent element.
As in I want to find 'target-me-1' element within and only within the specific 'parent-1' elements.
**Is it possible to find an element only within a selected element?**

Comment: can you show us what did you tried? Or paste your code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elements found in browser are also searchable

```py
from selenium import webdriver 

URL = 'url'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(URL)

lst = browser.find_elements_by_id("parent 1")
for parent in lst:
    target = parent.find_element_by_class_name("target-me-1")
    # print(target.text)
```